# calculate the full turns of a circle

Tags: javascript

i am stuck on this homework question

I cannot figure out how to count beyond 360 degrees. I am given 4 sets of degrees 90, 368, 809 and 2500 as the arguments.

```
function calculateFullTurns(degrees) {
    // return the number of full turns you can make with the provided degrees
    // 1 full turn === 360 degrees
```

Comment: have you tried to divide the number?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the sum of all the arguments using `reduce()` and divide by `360`. Also use `Math.floor()` on result because you want full turns

```js
function fullTurns(...args){
  return Math.floor(args.reduce((ac,a) => ac+a,0)/360)
}
console.log(fullTurns(90, 368, 809,2500))
```

Comment: Since this uses ES6 syntax so it may not work on all browsers

Comment: @Faizan Thanks  but  OP didn't mentioned anywhere about not using ES6 or working in in all the browsers

Comment: @Faizan At this point, ES6 is supported by 92% of users - unless you're specifically targeting IE 11, there's no reason not to use it.